# Emacs hydra insert/append text

Tags: emacs, tags, hydra

I want to be able to insert tags with an hydra while capturing my todos or in files. I tried doing it with the insert-buffer command but it seems to not be working. But this also seems to be unpractical...
Is there a command with which I could append a text defined in the config.el or different strings from one file?

```
 (defhydra hydra-tags (:color pink
                             :hint nil)
  "
^Tag^
^^^^^^^^-
_h_: home
_w_: work
_a_: assignments 
_f_: family
"
  ("h" insert-buffer "~/org/tags/home.txt")
  ("w" insert-buffer "~/org/tags/work.txt")
  ("a" insert-buffer "~/org/tags/assignments.txt")
  ("f" insert-buffer "~/org/tags/family.txt")
  ("q" quit-window "quit" :color blue))

(define-key org-capture-mode-map "." 'hydra-tags/body)
```

Comment: are the tags you are trying to insert listed in those files?

Comment: Yes indeed, there is one word per file. Although it seems to be adding the current open buffers link instead of the defined files content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite new to emacs and have no knowledge of lisp but I found out that this can easily be done with a simple lisp function.

I'll share the code I ended up with. Feel free to share any advice!

[elisp text editing functions](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_text_editing_functions.html)

```
(defhydra hydra-tags (:hint none)
 "
^Tag
^----------------
_h_: home
_j_: work
_k_: assignments
_l_: family
"
 ("h" (insert ":home:"))
 ("j" (insert ":work:"))
 ("k" (insert ":assignments:"))
 ("l" (insert ":family:"))
 ("q" quit-window "quit" :color blue))

(global-set-key (kbd "C-c k") 'hydra-tags/body)
```